# Help with modeling to UV mapping

Tags: uv

I'm new to blender. I wonder to know how to model things that can successfully create its UV Mapping. Are there any tips?

As you can see, I model a coat but it doesn't work with UV mapping. If anyone knows what's happening on my coat, please let me know. Thank you!
   [image: I create a coat but it doesn't work with UV mapping.]
[image]

I got the UV mapping which looks not good. I wonder are there any tips to mark seam? 
[image: unwrap]

I used smart UV projects and I got the one looks better. But there are a lot of islands on UV editor, is that ok?
[image: I used smart UV projects]

Comment: You need to add some "Seams" to your model. Select an Edge Loop and press CTRL + E > Mark Seam". This tells Blender where to unfold the mesh. There is a good tutorial here (Part 5) https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/2018/1/17/creating-an-anvil-full-series

Comment: @Dontwalk Hi, I followed your advice and watched the tutorial. And I still wonder if there are some tips to mark seam or something that I should take care when modeling. I have edited my question just before. If you know how to solve please let me know. Thanks for sharing tutorials. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you don't see your UV map, is blender doesn't preview image textures unless you change the view mode.

If you look at your 3D window on the right... at the bottom toolbar... next to the words "edit mode" is a little box with a white ball. This is where you change the view mode. Right now it's in "solid" mode, so no textures, just solid mesh shape.

Click it and choose "Material" mode. Then you'll see your image textures applied to the mesh. You could also go into rendered view by pressing shift+Z, and you can exit rendered mode with shift+Z again. Rendered view will also show your image textures. But it might not show anything if you haven't added lights and positioned your camera yet. So first try material view.

Comment: Hi, I've followed your advice and  I saw UV mapping on my coat! But the UV mapping looks not good, so I tried smart UV projects and I got the one which looks better, but there are a lot of islands on UV editor. Does it matter if there are so many islands? Or are there any tips to mark seam? :)

Comment: @CreeDorofi I have edited my questions. If you know how to solve my problems please let me know. :)

Comment: it's ok if there's lots of islands, the main thing is there's not much stretching, and the texture appears in the places you want. I sometimes use smart UV project too instead of making my own seams, it does a pretty good job on some things. If you wanted to make better seams "manually" then... I might google for blender seams in clothing, and see if other people already found the best place to mark seams in coats, shirts, etc.